# Keep checkbox checked after reload or refresh page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make a filtering of products on my page with ajax, jquery and php.

I make the pagination with ajax and works very good but I don't know how to make  filters.

1. How to keep checkbox checked after reload or refresh page?

In js I have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

load_data(1);

function load_data(page, query = '', qry_stoc = '')
{
  $.ajax({
    url:"ajax/fetch.php?cat=52",
    method:"POST",
    data:{page:page, query:query, qry_stoc: qry_stoc},
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
    }
  });
}

var stoc = $('.qry_stoc').val();

$(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
  var page = $(this).data('page_number');
  var query = $('#search_box').val();
  var stoc = $('.qry_stoc').val();

  load_data(page, query, stoc);
});

$('#search_box').keyup(function(){
  var query = $('#search_box').val();
  load_data(1, query);
});

$('.qry_stoc').on('change', function() {
  var data = $('.qry_stoc').serializeArray();

  var stoc = $('.qry_stoc').val();
  load_data(1, stoc);
});
```

});

Comment: There are only two ways to store user selected data. On the client side with cookies or on the backend side in a database. I guess in your position I woulld start using cookies

Comment: I want filering products on my website but i don't have an tutorial.....